# Generate CSV file from string[][]

Tags: c#, file, csv

I have a MVC controller that should return a CSV file from a `string[][]`. I'm trying this example:

```
public FileContentResult DownloadCSV()
{
    string[][] output = new string[][]{  
            new string[]{"Col 1 Row 1", "Col 2 Row 1", "Col 3 Row 1"},  
            new string[]{"Col1 Row 2", "Col2 Row 2", "Col3 Row 2"}  
        };
    return File(output, "text/csv", "Report123.csv");
}
```

But I don't know how to create the file. How can I create a CSV file from `string[][]`?

Comment: On which part are you stuck?  Opening/creating the file? creating the comma-separated list?  writing to the file?

Comment: In the Return File, i dont know how to create the file

Comment: The file contents should be a `Byte[]`, not a `string[][]`. Look up how to convert a string to a byte array.

Comment: `File.WriteAllLines("Report123.csv", output.Select(inner => string.Join(",", inner)));`

Comment: You need to considered escaped characters. I would not reccomend trying to produce your own csv. There are plenty of free tools availbable that will give you great flexibility and speed, as well as robustness in corner cases you may not consider. CSVHelper available at nuget is a great resource. here is a link to the spec. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample using LINQ.

```
public FileContentResult DownloadCSV()
{
    string[][] output = new string[][]{  
        new string[]{"Col 1 Row 1", "Col 2 Row 1", "Col 3 Row 1"},  
        new string[]{"Col1 Row 2", "Col2 Row 2", "Col3 Row 2"}  
    };

    var result = lines.Select(l=>string.Join(",", l))
                      .Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, v) => sb.AppendLine(v))
                      .ToString();

    return File(result, "text/csv", "Report123.csv");
}
```

... as an extension method ...

```
public static class ToolsEx
{
    public static string ToCsvString(this string[][] lines)
    {
        var query = lines.Select(l=>string.Join(",", l));
        var result = query.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, v) => sb.AppendLine(v));
        return result.ToString();
    }
}
```

... after remembering that `string.Join` uses StringBuilder internal you could reduce this further to just be (this might be a bit much if someone else is going to maintain this after you) ...

```
public static string ToCsvString(this string[][] rows)
{
    return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, rows.Select(row => string.Join(",", row)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an extension method to generate the [csv](/questions/tagged/csv) file

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Convert an array to string list, of the form "1,2,3,.."        
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="array">The array of numbers</param>
    /// <returns>A string value</returns>
    public static string ToCSVRow<T>(this T[] array)
    {
        string[] parts=new string[array.Length];
        for(int i=0; i<parts.Length; i++)
        {
            parts[i]=array[i].ToString();
        }
        return string.Join(",", parts);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Convert a jagged array to csv table, where each row has the form "1,2,3,.."
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="array">The array of numbers</param>
    /// <returns>A string value</returns>
    public static string ToCSV<T>(this T[][] array)
    {
        List<string> csv=new List<string>();
        for(int i=0; i<array.Length; i++)
        {
            csv.Add(array[i].ToCSVRow());
        }
        return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, csv.ToArray());
    }
```

and use with

```
return File(output.ToCSV(), "text/csv", "Report123.csv");
```

**Edit 1**

Based on the comments it would be simpler and maybe faster to do the following:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Convert an array to a csv row, of the form "1,2,3,4.."
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The array type</typeparam>
    /// <param name="list">The array</param>
    /// <returns>A comma delimited string</returns>
    public static string ToCSVRow<T>(this T[] list)
    {
        return string.Join(",", list);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Convert a jagged array to csv table, where each row has the form "1,2,3,.."
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="array">The array of numbers</param>
    /// <returns>A string value</returns>
    public static string ToCSV<T>(this T[][] array)
    {
        return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, array.Select((row) => string.Join(",", row)));
    }
```

Comment: Alternatively you can use `StringBulder` instead of `List<string>`

Comment: The number of times this data would be iterated over in this example makes me sad.  

You really don't need the for loop inside of the `ToCSVRow` method as the `string.Join` method takes an `object[]`.  `string.Join` also takes an `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerable<string>` so you could just pass it a simple LINQ expression over `array` (change the 'ToCSV' function to `return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, array.Select(ToolsEx.ToCSVRow))`) ... this would provide cleaner code, take less time to process and cause many less iterations.